# How to calculate the point lying on the outer circle following the tagent line of the inner circle

Tags: 2d, geometry, points

My question is about calculating points coordinates in 2D space.
I have two circles - outer and inner, that are centered between them (the inner is in the middle of the outer).

**What I know:**
-the two circles' radiuses (R1,R2)
-the 2D coordinates of a random point (x) in space always outside of the inner circle

**What I want to find out:**
-The 2D coordinates of the two points (y,z) that are lying on the outer circle following the two tangent lines from the random point (x)

Here is an illustration of what I need
[image]

Comment: Use [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html) twice. First for obtained coordinate point of intersection tangent line and  small cycle(case  determines =0, this equation solve problem). Second to intersection line (that have coordinate of two point, calculate from first step) and big cycle.
Condition of point is in space always outside of the inner circle - *not used.* When point is between two cycle answer was the same!

Answer (score 2):

Let's circles' center is coordinate origin `(0,0)` (shift other coordinates by true center ones), random point is `P`, point at big circle is `Q`, small radius is `r`, larger one is `R`.

We could build a system of equations for distance from center to tangent point and for intersection point, but it requires solving of quartic equation with rather long coefficients.

So at first find equation of tangent from point P to small circle with trigonometry:

```
Dist = Sqrt(px^2+py^2)
tan_angle = ArcSin(r / Dist)
rot_angle = ArcTan2(py, px)

ta1 = rot_angle - tan_angle
ta2 = rot_angle + tan_angle

and tangent points are
t1x = r * sin(ta1)
t1y = - r * cos(ta1)

t2x = - r * sin(ta2)
t2y = r * cos(ta2)
```

Now for both tangent points solve quadratic equation like

```
(px + s * (t1x - px))^2 + (py + s * (t1y - py))^2 = R^2
```

for unknown parameter s, get two solutions `s1,s`2 and find points of intersections

```
q11x = px + s1 * (t1x - px)
and so on
```

Note that solution consists of four points - two tangents, two intersection points for every tangent.